# Is it possible to use ASP.NET Core + IdentityServer4 JWT in AWS PrivateLink?

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, identityserver4, nlb

I've been running my web API under AWS Windows VM with IIS using **Asp.Net Core** and **IdentityServer4**.
The Identity Server is running on the same application of my secured controller.
This is running perfectly with no issue using my external domain of 'http://{my-external-domain}'.

My StartUp.cs relevant portion looks like the following:

```
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = xyzConfig.Authority; //http://{my-external-domain}
            options.Audience = "xyz";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
```

I'm using http://{my-external-domain}/connect/token and then I can request the authorized content successfully.

However, when setting this flow using the **AWS PrivateLink** some combinations aren't working including the desired one of http://{my-internal-domain} as the issuer/authority and the secured controller.

Using the StartUp settings above I get a 500 error saying the following:

```
IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'http://{my-internal-domain}/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
```

However, from the same machine it's possible to retrieve this information:

```
{
"issuer": "http://{my-internal-domain}",
"jwks_uri": "http://{my-internal-domain}/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
"authorization_endpoint": "http://{my-internal-domain}/connect/authorize",
"token_endpoint": "http://{my-internal-domain}/connect/token",
"userinfo_endpoint": "http://{my-internal-domain}/connect/userinfo",
"end_session_endpoint": "http://{my-internal-domain}/connect/endsession",
"check_session_iframe": "http://{my-internal-domain}/connect/checksession",
"revocation_endpoint": "http://{my-internal-domain}/connect/revocation",
"introspection_endpoint": "http://{my-internal-domain}/connect/introspect",
"device_authorization_endpoint": "http://{my-internal-domain}/connect/deviceauthorization",
"frontchannel_logout_supported": true,
"frontchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
"backchannel_logout_supported": true,
"backchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
"scopes_supported": [
    "openid",
    "email",
    "profile",
    "xyz",
    "offline_access"
],
"claims_supported": [
    "sub",
    "email",
    "email_verified",
    "name",
    "family_name",
    "given_name",
    "middle_name",
    "nickname",
    "preferred_username",
    "profile",
    "picture",
    "website",
    "gender",
    "birthdate",
    "zoneinfo",
    "locale",
    "updated_at"
],
"grant_types_supported": [
    "authorization_code",
    "client_credentials",
    "refresh_token",
    "implicit",
    "password",
    "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code"
],
"response_types_supported": [
    "code",
    "token",
    "id_token",
    "id_token token",
    "code id_token",
    "code token",
    "code id_token token"
],
"response_modes_supported": [
    "form_post",
    "query",
    "fragment"
],
"token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
    "client_secret_basic",
    "client_secret_post"
],
"subject_types_supported": [
    "public"
],
"id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "RS256"
],
"code_challenge_methods_supported": [
    "plain",
    "S256"
],
"request_parameter_supported": true
```

}

When I changed the StartUp.cs settings to the following:

```
var key = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xyzConfig.Secret); 
        
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            //options.Authority = xyzConfig.Authority;
            options.Audience = "xyz";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
           
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });
```

Now I get 401 with the following message in the response header:

```
Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"
```

This was pretty interesting as the token used here seems valid when parsed in jsonwebtoken.io:

```
{
"nbf": 1602077163,
"exp": 1602080774,
"iss": "http://{my-internal-domain}",
"aud": [
 "http://{my-internal-domain}/resources",
 "xyz"
],
"client_id": "789456",
"sub": "23de9244-86ba-4553-845f-1cbe6bac0536",
"auth_time": 1602077162,
"idp": "local",
"given_name": "gname",
"email": "email@white.com",
"scope": [
 "openid",
 "xyz"
],
"amr": [
 "pwd"
],
"jti": "921552fd-da9b-49b0-98a6-c7c0dcb2d865",
"iat": 1602077174
```

}

That also comes with the `Signing Key    Verified` so now I don't know which way should we go now and if anyways we can run the JWT authentication using **AWS PrivateLink** that uses their **Network Load Balancer (NLB)**

If any other info is required I'll be happy to provide here.
Any help is appreciated here, thanks!